# Use rename of unknown string length

Tags: bash, rename

I have some files

```
"file 1 [EN MR RE EF SF DS DE].txt"
"file 2 [EN MR].txt"
"file 3 [EN MR RE EF].txt"
```

Id like to use `rename` to remove the `[ * ]` section.

I've tried:

```
rename  -n 's/\[*]//g' *.mkv
```

`rename` doesn't work with `*` so I've become stuck.

Output should be

```
"file 1.txt"
"file 2.txt"
"file 3.txt"
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome, still note that your command says `*.mkv` extensions, but your examples are `*.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perl based `rename` command's `s` operator takes *regular expressions* not shell wildcards. The regular expression for any character zero or more times is `.*`, not `*`. In addition, `[` and `]` have special meanings and must be escaped if you want them to match literally. So:

```
$ rename -n 's/ \[.*\]//' file*.txt
rename(file 1 [EN MR RE EF SF DS DE].txt, file 1.txt)
rename(file 2 [EN MR].txt, file 2.txt)
rename(file 3 [EN MR RE EF].txt, file 3.txt)
```

Remove the `-n` once you are happy with the proposed substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a loop and the standard utility `mv`:

```sh
for i in *.txt; do
  mv "$i" "${i% [*}.txt"
done
```